# Detect Updates To Entities Bound to an (editable) JTable

Tags: java, swing, binding, jpa, jtable

What is the appropriate method to detect changes made to an entity through an editable cell in a JTable? I would like to get the entity which the changes occurred so that I can commit the changes using JPA (eclipselink).

So far I tried a `TableModelListener` implementation. However, it seems that the `TableModelEvent` does not provide a reference to the underlying entity (or data provider of the table) object but only to the value (Object) which has changed.

Having a background in AS3, I'm used to writing event driven code. But, what is the right approach to implement this in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either inspect the row of the TableModelEvent fired by the modification, and ask your model the entity at this row, or fire another dedicated event when a cell is updated, containing the updated entity.

See the [Swing tutorial on tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for how to create your own table model, extending AbstractTableModel. It's almost always better than using the default one, and I thought you were doing it already, because you said that *"changes [were] made to an entity through an editable cell"*.

Comment: But how exactly do I get the entity asking my model? Can I get the underlying data (entity) through the table model or do I need to implement my own model? It would be easy to get the entity if I had access to the id, but I don't see how to accomplish this.

Comment: @userXXXX - TableModel and its default implementation does not support access to your entity, you need a custom implementation

Comment: Ah - getting closer, thank you very much. I will have a look at the `TableModel`
@JB Nizet - sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that there is a much simpler way to get the updated entity if the data (entities) is bound to the `JTable` using a `BindingGroup` (which is the case in my case):

```
bindingGroup.addBindingListener( new AbstractBindingListener() {

    @Override
    public void synced(Binding binding) {

        super.synced(binding);

        // the entity object
        Object sourceObject = binding.getSourceObject();   
    } 
}
```

I'm certain that the same could be achieved using a custom `TableModel` and may be the proper approach. However, the above implementation is just much easier in my case.

Comment: important omission in your question ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra - I definitely agree, but just didn't know at the time of asking. NetBeans makes this binding stuff so easy that - as a beginner - you have no idea of what is happening code-wise.